# how to use dynamic modules with file browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, tkinter, module

Basically when my program is run, I would like it to come up with a file browser where I can select a python program which will be imported as a module. This is what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()

x = askopenfilename()

print(x)

#g = __import__(x)
```

The problem is this grabs the whole path of the file, not just the filename. And even if it did grab just the filename, I'd have to remove the .py from the end.

So basically my question is, is there an easier way of achieving what I want? If not, then how do I strip off all of the path information and and the file extension to leave me with just the module name?

To add a bit of context, what this program will eventually do is us a meter to take voltage measurements, but I want it to be interchangeable as to what meter I use. As each meter will communicate differently I want to write all of the commands for each meter in their own file, and select which meter I want to use each time I run it. And no, I do not just want to type in the name of the module, I'd like to be able to browse for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[os.path](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html) includes everything you need.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from os.path import basename, splitext

Tk().withdraw()

path = askopenfilename()
file = basename(path)
(filename, fileextension) = splitext(file)

print(filename)
```

Comment: Crap. Posted mine 2 minutes after yours. Guess you beat me to the punch this time.

Comment: This is almost beautiful in its simplicity :) Thank you very much, worked like a charm!